# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined PDO Insert Statement

Tags: php, pdo, insert

I have a problem with my PDO INSERT.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);
include "../includes/php/db.php";

$name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
$stadt = htmlentities($_POST['stadt']);
$postleitzahl = htmlentities($_POST['postleitzahl']);
$strasse = htmlentities($_POST['straße']);
$hausnummer = htmlentities($_POST['hausnummer']);
$created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$updated_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO kundens (name, stadt, postleitzahl, straße, hausnummer, created_at, updated_at)VALUES( :name, :stadt, :postleitzahl, :strasse, :hausnummer, :created_at, :updated_at)');

var_dump($name, $stadt, $postleitzahl, $strasse, $hausnummer, $created_at, $updated_at);
try {
    $stmt->execute(array($name, $stadt, $postleitzahl, $strasse, $hausnummer, $created_at, $updated_at));
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Insert Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

I can't find my problem.

The DB is like this:

```
#   Name                Typ Kollation   Attribute               Null    Standard    Kommentare      Extra
1   idPrimärschlüssel   int(10)         UNSIGNED                Nein    kein(e)     AUTO_INCREMENT
2   name                varchar(255)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci      Nein    kein(e)     
3   stadt               varchar(255)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci      Nein    kein(e)     
4   postleitzahl        int(11)                                 Nein    kein(e)     
5   straße              varchar(255)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci      Nein    kein(e)     
6   hausnummer          int(11)                                 Nein    kein(e)     
7   created_at          timestamp                               Ja      NULL        
8   updated_at          timestamp                               Ja      NULL
```

Comment: Better use `?` instead of named parameters `:abc` if you not useing the names with `bindParam()`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I guess this one could swing either way

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using named parameters rather than ? parameters you have to name your array key accordingly.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO kundens (name, stadt, postleitzahl, straße, hausnummer, created_at, updated_at)VALUES( :name, :stadt, :postleitzahl, :strasse, :hausnummer, :created_at, :updated_at)');

try {
    $stmt->execute(
        array(
            'name' => $name,
            'stadt' => $stadt,
            'postleitzahl' => $postleitzahl,
            'strasse' => $strasse,
            'hausnummer' => $hausnummer,
            'created_at' => $created_at,
            'updated_at' => $updated_at
        )
    );
```

Comment: Ok its not :O It inserted one and since then its not giving out any single error but dont inserts anything

Comment: If you aren't getting an error and it's not inserting, there's two possible problems. 1) The problem is somewhere else 2) PDO isn't in exception mode so the error isn't being thrown